# Parameter Checks as Null/Undefined Despite Console Showing a Value

Tags: javascript

I have a function that references things. For the purpose of fixing the bug, I've removed other case statements (they don't change nor fix the problem). I have also removed the `return`, because that's irrelevant at this stage too.

For some reason, say I pass an element in the DOM: `Referencer('id', 'hello')`, despite Chrome Console telling me that `type = 'id'` that `if (type === null || "" || "undefined")` fires every single time.

Here's a JSBin: https://output.jsbin.com/secuciyeko

```
function Referencer(type, value) {

    // Standard Declaration
    "use strict";

    // Open Console Group
    window.console.groupCollapsed("[Scriptbase.js]/[Referencer] @ " + Scriptbase.Time());

    // Log Status
    window.console.info("[Process Started @ " + Scriptbase.Time() + "]");







    /* ------- Computation ------- */

    // Local Variables
    var a = null;

    // Log Status
    window.console.log("[Success @ " + Scriptbase.Time() + "]: Checking for unusable values.");

    // Value Validation
    if (type === null || "" || "undefined") {

        // Log Status
        window.console.error("[Failure : " + Scriptbase.Time() + "] : Failure to look up '" + type + "' with the value '" + value + "'.");

        // Close Console Group
        window.console.groupEnd();

        // Exit Method
        return;

    }
    if (value === null || "" || "undefined") {

        // Log Status
        window.console.error("[Failure : " + Scriptbase.Time() + "] : Failure to look up '" + type + "' with the value '" + value + "'.");

        // Close Console Group
        window.console.groupEnd();

        // Exit Method
        return;

    }

    // Log Status
    window.console.log("[Success : " + Scriptbase.Time() + "] : Looking up '" + type.toUpperCase() + "' with the value of '" + value + "'.");

    // Look Up Value
    switch (type) {
        case "id":

            // Variable Assignment
            a = document.getElementById(value);

            // Log Status
            window.console.log("[Success : " + Scriptbase.Time() + "]: Found an DOM ID of '" + value + "'.");

            // Break Case
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this

```
if (type === null || "" || "undefined") {
```

You are saying:

- if `type` is equal to `null`
- or if empty string is true
- or if string `'undefined'` is true

You are not actually comparing `type` to `''` or `'undefined'`.

You can change to

```
if (!type) {
```

Then if it is empty, `null` or `undefined` it will go in the condition.

Read about

- [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
- [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)